# How to get UDP server to respond to a UDP client packet?

Tags: java, sockets, io, udp

I'm having trouble getting the server to send data back to the client. Here is my code and my inputs and results.

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.DatagramPacket;
import java.net.DatagramSocket;
import java.net.InetAddress;

public class UDPServer {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        InetAddress ip = InetAddress.getByName("127.0.0.1");
        int port = 1345;

        //Creates connection socket.
        DatagramSocket serverSocket = new DatagramSocket(port);

        System.out.println("Server Active");
        while(true) {
            //Receiving packet
            byte[] buffer = new byte[100];
            DatagramPacket receivePacket = new DatagramPacket(buffer, buffer.length);
            serverSocket.receive(receivePacket);
            String clientInput = new String(buffer);
            System.out.println("Server has Received : " + clientInput);

            //Sending packet
            byte[] data = clientInput.getBytes();
            DatagramPacket sendPack = new DatagramPacket(data, data.length, ip, port);
            serverSocket.send(sendPack);
            String serverInput = new String(data);
            System.out.println("Server has sent: " + serverInput);
        }

    }
}
```

~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.DatagramSocket;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.DatagramPacket;
import java.net.InetAddress;


public class UDPClient
{
    public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException
    {
        DatagramSocket clientSocket = new DatagramSocket();
        InetAddress ip = InetAddress.getByName("127.0.0.1");
        BufferedReader inFromUser = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        int port = 1345;

        System.out.println("Would you like to continue?");
        while(inFromUser.readLine().equals("Yes") || inFromUser.readLine().equals("yes")) {
            System.out.println("Enter an expression to be evaluated");

            //gets userInput
            String userInput = inFromUser.readLine();
            byte[] buffer = userInput.getBytes();

            //sends packet to server
            DatagramPacket sendPacket = new DatagramPacket(buffer, buffer.length, ip, port);
            clientSocket.send(sendPacket);
            System.out.println("Client has sent: " + userInput);

            //receives packet from server
            byte[] data = new byte[100];
            DatagramPacket receivePacket = new DatagramPacket(data, data.length);
            clientSocket.receive(receivePacket);
            String serverInput = new String(data);
            System.out.println("Client has received: " + serverInput);
            System.out.println("Would you like to continue?");
        }
    }
}
```

I am not sure why the server does not echo back to the client? I'm not sure what I am doing wrong, or about the overall quality of this code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The server is sending the reply to itself. When you create the `sendPacket` in the server, you're giving it `ip` and `port` but the `ip` and `port` are the server's own IP and bound (listening) port, not the port of your client.

Because the client created its `DatagramSocket` without specifying a port, the system will dynamically choose an unused port number for it. You need to obtain the client's port number with `receivePacket.getSocketAddress()` (in the server), then use that address in your construction of `sendPacket`. In fact, there is an alternate constructor for `DatagramPacket` that accepts buffer, length and `SocketAddress` which is ideal for constructing the reply packet.

Comment: What's even easier is to reuse the request packet for the reply. It already has the target address in it. Just set the data and length for the reply, and send it.

Comment: I'm sorry is there a way you can restate this statement I am trying to visualize the idea you have presented in code, maybe it is my fault for labeling my variables very similiar

Comment: @silversk8terz: on the server side, change `DatagramPacket sendPack = new DatagramPacket(data, data.length, ip, port);` to `DatagramPacket sendPack = new DatagramPacket(data, data.length, receivePacket.getSocketAddress());`  Or, simply get rid of `sendPack` altogether and just use `receivePacket.setData(data); serverSocket.send(receivePacket);` instead

Comment: Thank you guys! so much now I'm going to try to finish this last step and see if i can get it done thank you so much